# How Can I get multi-Dimensional array by value

Tags: postgresql, json, postgresql-9.5

In `PostgreSQL 9.5` I use `jsonb` column called user_tag. This column has multi dimensional array like this:

```
[{"id": 1, "tag": "@xang"}, {"id": 2, "tag": "@wang"}]
```

I want to get when `id` is equal to `1`. I can do this by following query:

```
SELECT * FROM mydb AS f WHERE f.user_tag #>> '{0,id}' = '1'
```

But, I have to provide `0` as a key. I want to search all `id` columns and return matched table rows. If I already know `0`, why would i search in first place.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Note: `SELECT * FROM mydb AS f WHERE f.user_tag ->> 'id' = '1'` is not worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it myself. I wil llet you guys know so may other people get use it.

```
SELECT * FROM mydb AS f WHERE f.user_tag @> '[{"id":1}]'
```

That' s it. I can now get rows contains **id=1**